# how to concatenate text in mail body using vba when we need to use IF THEN condition in between?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to combine text in mail body and also i need to use IFTHEN condition. how should I proceed. Below given is the code, you can see the If condition between body.

```
Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Object
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim last As Integer
    x = 3
    i = 2

    last = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(23, 2).Value = last

    Do While i <= last

        If x - i = 1 Then

        olMail.To = Cells(i, 8).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 9).Value

        olMail.Subject = "Subject"
        olMail.Body = 
        "Document details as follows:" & vbNewLine & _
        "Title                 : " & Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "EP Number     : " & Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "Product Type  : " & Cells(i, 4).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "Well(s)             : " & Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "Field(s)             : " & Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Straight Link to the document : " & Cells(i, 7).FormulaR1C1 & _
        If Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(x, 8).Value Then
        "Document details as follows:" & vbNewLine & _
        "Title                 : " & Cells(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "EP Number     : " & Cells(x, 5).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "Product Type  : " & Cells(x, 4).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "Well(s)             : " & Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
        "Field(s)             : " & Cells(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Straight Link to the document : " & Cells(x, 7).FormulaR1C1
        x = x + 1

        End If

        Else
        olMail.Send
        i = x
        x = x + 1

        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reuse what you already stored in the body inside of the `If` :

```
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Object
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim last As Integer
x = 3
i = 2

last = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(23, 2).Value = last

Do While i <= last

    If x - i = 1 Then

    olMail.To = Cells(i, 8).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 9).Value

    olMail.Subject = "Subject"
    olMail.Body = _
    "Document details as follows:" & vbNewLine & _
    "Title                 : " & Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
    "EP Number     : " & Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
    "Product Type  : " & Cells(i, 4).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
    "Well(s)             : " & Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
    "Field(s)             : " & Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Straight Link to the document : " & Cells(i, 7).FormulaR1C1
        If Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(x, 8).Value Then
            olMail.Body = olMail.Body & vbNewLine & _
            "Document details as follows:" & vbNewLine & _
            "Title                 : " & Cells(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
            "EP Number     : " & Cells(x, 5).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
            "Product Type  : " & Cells(x, 4).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
            "Well(s)             : " & Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & _
            "Field(s)             : " & Cells(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Straight Link to the document : " & Cells(x, 7).FormulaR1C1
            x = x + 1
        End If

    Else
    olMail.Send
    i = x
    x = x + 1

    End If
Loop
```